# display file from blob data oracle - Angular/Java

Tags: java, angular, rest, blob

New to Stack Overflow, Pardon if I miss adding any details in the question.

Requirement:
I have various types of files (pdf, jpg, HTML, CVS, etc) saved as BLOB data in the oracle. I have an angular component and a REST Service. the task is to retrieve the blob data and send it to the front-end angular component in the rest service response. After getting the response, need to display the file in a new tab or a pop-up window.

Questions:
How can I send the blob data in rest service response so that I can convert it to a file and display it in the UI? (Is this possible?)

Comment: Servlet based example https://www.baeldung.com/servlet-download-file

Answer (score 0):

SELECT dbms_lob.substr( clob_field, 4000, 1 ) FROM my_table;